# How do I delete an Index using NEST 7.4.1?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to Elastic search and I have written code to index a list of City. I am using "elasticsearch head" add-on for chrome to check and manipulate the indexes and _doc.

While indexing and CRUD operation of doc is resulting correctly, I had to delete the index manually via elastic-search add-on.

I want to check for the index first, if an index is available, delete it, and create the index & index the list of City again. This is what I want to do. But getting an error in Delete() method saying

> argument 1: cannot convert from string to Nest.IDeleteRequest

Following is my code to show you what I am doing:

```
        public async Task<List<BulkResponseItemBase>> AddNewIndex(string index_name, List<City> model)
        {
            client = new ElasticClient(elstcstngs);
            List<BulkResponseItemBase> elstcManyrespoStatusList = new List<BulkResponseItemBase>();
            if (await CheckIndexExists(index_name))
            {
               //This is where I am getting error - Cannot Convert from string to Nest.IDeleteRequest
                client.Delete(index_name); 
            }
            elstcstngs.DefaultMappingFor<City>(m => m.IndexName(index_name));
            BulkResponse elstcManyrespoStatus = await client.IndexManyAsync<City>(model, null);
            if (elstcManyrespoStatus.Errors)
            {
                foreach (var itemWithError in elstcManyrespoStatus.ItemsWithErrors)
                {
                    elstcManyrespoStatusList.Add(itemWithError);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to index document {0}: {1}", itemWithError.Id, itemWithError.Error);
                }
            }
            return elstcManyrespoStatusList;
        }
```

I have searched the Elastic search Documentation but could not find any API in NEST 7.4.1 documentation, which will delete the *index* itself.
Instead what I am getting is of NEST version 1.x.

Any link towards a documentation or any help regarding the code will very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: `client.Delete` method does not accept index name as parameter. It requires DeleteRequest object. That's what the error says. Or you need to use DeleteIndex method. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/delete-indices.html

Comment: I haven't had luck looking for an example in the docs either, but it looks like the newer version of the API does not work with `.Delete(indexname)`, but rather with `.Delete(new DeleteRequest(…))`. Which implementations of `IDeleteRequest` do exist? Can you instantiate one of them and parametrize them with the index name?

Comment: No, It was throwing error. Now you have the same ```Delete()``` Inside ```Indices``` property. Feeling dumb, why I could not get it earlier.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you can see from `client.Delete` method description 
[image]

it exposes elasticsearch [delete API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-delete.html) which is responsible for deleting documents from elasticsearch.

If you want to remove index you can do this with

```
await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("index_name");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there a way to disable that so the user will not be able to delete indeces using this code? Question for my acceptance tests.

Comment: @Marin not sure what you are trying to achieve, could you please put some more context?

Answer (score 0):

With the last version by 2023-04-12 following code works:

```
client.Indices.Delete(new DeleteIndexRequest(Indices.Index("IndexName")));
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to disable that so no user can delete indeces using this command? That's for Acceptance tests.

Comment: This is a C# program piece. You must manage who can run this code in the authorization section of the program yourself.